# Nice line-break in inline math within theorem environment

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, theorems, inline

This is my first question here, I hope it's not bad (please bear with me if it is).

I have quite a specific problem concerning inline math and theorem environment. In general, I want to obtain the behavior of `\align` or `amsmath \multline` in inline math and theorem environment (I am using [LNCS](http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs/lncs+authors?SGWID=0-40209-0-0-0) style file, so it is actually either `definition` or `\spnewtheorem`).

To be more specific: I have a long logical formula within `definition` with a normal line break which makes the formula not very clear (see image below).

```
\begin{definition}
$UNT_{2}(a,b) \equiv_{\text{df}}\exists t_1\exists t_3 > t_1[(a \in t_1) \land  (b \in t_3) \land (a \not\in t_3) \land \forall t_2( t_1<t_2<t_3 \to a \in t_2)]$
\end{definition}
```

[image: Normal line break]

I would like the formula to start on the same line as "Definition 3" but:

1. In a new line the formula should be aligned to the `\equiv` sign (I like the approach taken [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239926/82531) but I am not sure how to make it work with `\equiv`)
2. I would like to be able to control (at least to some extent) on which operator the formula breaks

I am aware of `breqn` package but it does not really work with inline math nor do the methods provided by `amsmath`. I tried using `description` but it doesn't help.
Of course I could just break my expression into a few expressions and try to make it work with `\\` and `\,` but this seems very bad.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `aligned`. I used `amsthm` for defining the environment, you should be able to adapt to `llncs`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
$\begin{aligned}[t]
 \mathit{UNT}_{2}(a,b) \equiv_{\mathrm{df}}{}
  & \exists t_1\exists t_3 > t_1[(a \in t_1)
    \land  (b \in t_3) \land (a \not\in t_3) \land {}\\
  & \forall t_2( t_1<t_2<t_3 \to a \in t_2)]
\end{aligned}$
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

The alignment point has been set after the equivalence symbol; for this it's necessary to have `{}` in order to ensure correct spacing.

[image]